# Is there a way to use a service account in SSIS when i want to access a file from fileserver and get the data to a database?

Tags: ssis

Is there a way to use a service account in SSIS when i want to access a file from fileserver and get the data to a database?

I cant find a good answer for this questian

- We have a fileserver
- To this folder i have a service account *(Not the one im logged in with)*
- I use SSIS

But when i insert the //FILESERVERNAME the account im logged in to dont have access, And this is not an option to solve.

I have a Username and logging to the service account that i want to use (Flat file) with this connection to the filerserver. But i can't find a place where to insert it. The modules i made sothe logged in person have to have the access. *(This will be a problem when i try to execute the Package from SQL server job agent also)*

I need to specify the account that have access to the filerserver

...and after that i think i can use EncryptSensetiveWithPassword to save the credential to the package so when i execute this SSIS package in SQL Server Job agent. It uses that account insend of the Job agent account.  Like when you have special New OLE DB Connection... with special service account with EncryptSensetiveWithPassword.*

- I execute the SSIS package with SQL Server Job Agent

So is there a solution where i can use the modulses with a specefik account loggin?

I have looked on this solution, to be able to force the job agent to execute the ssis package with a special Account. That have access to the fileserver by share.

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/run-an-ssis-package-under-a-different-account

And then you get an other error
*( The process could not be created for step 1 of job *** (reason: A required privilege is not held by the client) )*

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc9fa982-bf27-4a68-a86c-12b4d11a598a/lterrorgt-the-process-could-not-be-created-for-step-1-of-job-reason-a-required-privilege?forum=sqltools